# Apache CXF list of uncorrelatedExchanges grows until memory is exhausted

Tags: cxf, cxf-client

I have a long-running CXF SOAP connection to a physical device. Over time, I see the org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.soap.MAPCodec object retaining heap. It appears that the ConcurrentHashpMap uncorrelatedExchanges is growing and the entries in the map are not being cleared. After only 12 hours of running, this map now contains almost 54,000 entries. Is there a way I can clear out the uncorrelatedExchanges? I am using CXF 3.4.0.

Thanks, David

Answer (score 0):

Same here, the workaround is to use Weak keys in uncorrelatedExchanges... With https://guava.dev/

```java
    public static <T> boolean setPrivateFinalField(Class<T> clazz, String fieldName, T instance, Object value) {
        try {
            Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
            modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
            modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
            field.set(instance, value);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return false;
    }

        ....
        WSAddressingFeature wsAddressingFeature = new WSAddressingFeature();
        wsAddressingFeature.initialize(client, client.getBus());
        client.getInInterceptors().stream().filter(MAPCodec.class::isInstance).findAny().map(MAPCodec.class::cast).ifPresent(mapCodec -> {
            // OOM workaround on no-relates-to responses
            Map<Object, Object> weakMap = new MapMaker().weakKeys().weakValues().makeMap();
            setPrivateFinalField(MAPCodec.class, "uncorrelatedExchanges", mapCodec, weakMap);
        });
```